# Wordpress - it is impossible to edit the theme file through admin after FTP upload

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp

I would like to change the theme file through the Wordpress Admin Panel, in menu `Appearance > Theme Editor`, but I've got the message:

> Something went wrong. Your change may not have been saved. Please try again. There is also a chance that you may need to manually fix and upload the file over FTP.

Everything was working correctly before I've made some changes in the file and upload it through the FTP back to the server. I am able to change every other file in Theme Editor, but this one. The rights are the same as in other files I am able to change, the owner and group are the same too. It looks that everything should work, but this and only this one file I have updated via FTP I am not able to change through the Theme Editor of Wordpress Admin Panel.

Any idea what could be possibly wrong? What I have done wrong? Please help me somebody, in the most of the time I am on the "safe" network, and the server FTP is not accessible from my computer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

**Check Theme Permission**

One of the first things you got to check the theme files and folder permissions.

If you are running on shared hosting then mostly it would be alright. However, if using VPS or Cloud then you got to ensure the same user owns theme files as web server (Nginx or Apache HTTP) running.

**Modify File Permissions with chmod**

FYR :- https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/tools/modify-file-permissions-with-chmod/

**Check Security Plugins**

Are you using any security plugins? Do you have the option to check their logs to see how exactly your request is being treated?

Alternatively, you can quickly disable the security plugin and verify if that works.

Comment: Hi, I have checked the permissions and the owner:group. I am running on shared hosting. Unfortunately, I am not able to change file permissions with chmod, I have no ssh (or another command line) access to the server. I have only FTP access. But I've tried to change file permissions via FTP cli to 0666, but updating the file in the Theme Editor cause the same issue (I reverted permissions after this attempt). What do you mean with the "security plugins"? I don't know about anything.

Comment: But the strange is that the Theme Editor was working with this file before I've made the action via FTP, and now, I am still able to change the siblings of this file (files in the same directory with the same permissions).

Comment: security plugin means did you install any 3rd party plugins for the site. If you installed please disable  one by one and check if its working or not. Also check all the files are there after FTP.

Comment: Ok, now I understand, there are just a few of the 3rd party plugins. So, I have tried to deactivate them and it is still not working. And I have watched the Network panel of the Chrome debug console and the return code is 403. But I can't see anything more and I have no access to logs.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved the problem. There were two things with I have mislead my question.

The first one was that I wrote "Everything was working correctly before I've made some changes in the file and upload it through the FTP" and after that I wrote it again in the comment of the answer - I was so sure that I have tried the same file before, but I have not, it definitely was another one, I am sorry.

And the second was that I did not write specific file name. The file was `includes/_wp_utils.php`. Somebody would maybe notice that this is the biggest file in that directory. And that was the problem. I do not know why - maybe it was too big for server processing or something else (120KB), but I noticed it later, and I have tried to split the file to a few smaller files and I have included them into the `includes/_wp_utils.php` with the command `include_once __DIR__ . '/_wp_utils/_nth_part_of_original_wp_utils.php';`.

Thank you @G.D Udara Lahiru Sampath, I absolutely liked your answer. It was useful and very important to check.